# Custom lists, forms, and workflow creation

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've created a couple of lists (Laptop Checkout, Checkout Devices) and a form (Laptop Request) to aid in the tracking of some items.

I would like to be able to have a field from the laptop request form populate both lists with information.

The Laptop Checkout List gets populated directly from the Laptop Request form.
The Checkout Devices list is just a manual list I created with 3 devices on it.

Basically I have this column 'Device' on the form that is a dropdown selection box that is looking at my Checkout Device list 'Device' column.

When I click the dropdown on the form I get the 3 computers.

Is it possible to create a workflow in such a way that if the 3 devices are 'checked out' they will not show up in the dropdown box or show a message that says none available.

I have a column 'Available?' and 'Checked Out By' that I'd also like to pull data from the Checkout List

I wish I could explain better, maybe pictures would work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an out of the box way. But this can be done using REST and jQuery. Write a rest query to get only those items which are not checked out and on the success function bind the values to the Device drop-down.